# private visibility marker in PHP 7 behaves strange

Tags: php

I have a php class

```
class User{
 public $email;
 private $password = '1234'; //assigned here for simplicity
                             //same happens when assign from 
                             //inside a class  
}
```

now I try to use that class from other file

```
require './lib/User.php';
$john = new User();
$john->email = 'john@email'; //$email is public

var_dump($john->password);   //$password is private
```

and see nice message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property  User::$password in /home/pl/work/php/index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/work/php/index.php on line 5
```

ok. when I try

```
var_dump($john);
```

I see another nice message:

```
object(User)#1 (2) { ["email"]=> string(10) "john@email" ["password":"User":private]=> string(4) "1234" }
```

I'm not fully understand why this happens that way.

PHP version is

```
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016
```

Comment: What don't you understand?  A private property or method means you can only access it within that class' methods.

Comment: php has always shown private properties with var_dump, this isn't something new.

Comment: @Devon , I try to read private property from outside a class and from other file. In that `var_dump($john->password);` case I can't do this. But in that case `var_dump($john);` I can see private field. that is a question.

Comment: @d2048 Because var_dump is mainly use for debugging so it allows you to see private and protected properties even if you can't directly access them.

Comment: like devon said, var_dump is for debugging. You shouldn't worry about people using var_dump on your class. If they can view/write code that runs on your server, having someone var_dump a class instance is the least of your worries. Just don't push code to a production site that var_dumps the class and the password won't be shown. Or even disable the function in php.ini on your production site.